# Support library 26 CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I've had issues with the new support library 26.1.0, the same crap is going on with 27.0.0, however everything seems ok with 25.x.x.

Its a sample app from Android studio samples, Scrolling Activity.

HORRIBLE!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/imELj.jpg

I've made a video of just doing the fling behavior, and the snap scroll flag looks totally broken, also I don't know whats going on with the status bar, it seems like there is an overlay being drawn down by the force of a fling (facepalm).

Seriously Google, you ruin the support lib with every update. I'm really getting tired of the updates and looking after the whole app once the support lib changes. It's so ridiculous, you are the guys who developers should trust and rely on, but it seems that's not the case anymore, since you totally waste developers time, by always breaking things with the GUI.

This needs to be added to the theme under v21:

```
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Xml view

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: Is there any question here or just rant about support library/google?

Comment: Of course theres a question on how to fix this nasty bug, without reverting back to 25.x.x support lib!

Comment: The same issue on me :((( @box have you found any workaround ways? except reverting to 25.x.x

Comment: @nAkhmedov I reported the issue on AOSP https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69102146

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and managed to at least alleviate that weird behavior by just removing the **snap** from the layout_scrollFlags:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
```

However, you will lose snapping as you may guess.